# Tableau 8.2 - include links in table

Tags: hyperlink, tableau-api

I have links e.g. "http://www.google.de" included in my data set.

Could you guys give me a hint how I can include links in a table in tableau and allow the user to click on them and to open up in a new window.

I already included a webpage in my webpage therefore I think an action with URL is not possible.

I hope I could describe what I am searching for.

Looking forward to some expert tips - Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a dashboard URL action and give it the the field that contains the links.

See this workbook: https://public.tableausoftware.com/profile/emh2189#!/vizhome/www_1/Dashboard1 (click on a url and it will open a new tab).

You can download the workbook and see how it was put together.

Comment: I was looking EVERYWHERE for this solution. Thank you so, so much.